# powershell command to get network adapter connectivity status

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a Powershell command that will give me the Connectivity Status for all Network Adapters, for the ones where Connectivity equal "No network access" disable and re-enable the adapter.

First I need to get the correct status, I have tried the following command but it only shows the physically connection. Note the Status for all of them is Up even if the Connectivity status shows "No network access".

**Get-NetAdapter -physical**

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------
Ethernet 5                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#6      26 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 11               Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#7      23 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 10               Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#8      54 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 12               Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#4      17 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 6                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#5      15 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 4                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#3      13 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 9                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharin...#11      12 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 3                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#2      10 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 7                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing...#9       7 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I21...       6 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
Ethernet 8                Remote NDIS based Internet Sharin...#10       4 Up           XX-XX-XX-XX-X...
```

However, what I am trying to target is the **Connectivity** status as shown in the Network section

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

expanding on @postanote answer, it is more efficient to call Get-NetConnectionProfile once and store the results. I also used -eq instead of -match to ensure predictable results. Also if it is more than a 1-to-1 relationship the results could be unpredictable. His answer did not work on windows 10.

```
#get profiles and adapters
$Profiles = Get-NetConnectionProfile
$Adapters = Get-NetAdapter -Physical

#loop on adapters
$Results = $Adapters | ForEach-Object {
    #get the current adapter
    $Adapter = $PSItem
    #find the associated profiles
    $AdapterProfiles = $Profiles | where {$Adapter.ifIndex -eq $_.InterfaceIndex}

    #output the merged results by looping on the profiles
    $AdapterProfiles | 
         Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$Adapter.Name}},
                       @{n='DeviceName';e={$Adapter.DeviceName}},
                       @{n='InterfaceDescription';e={$Adapter.InterfaceDescription}},
                       @{n='Status';e={$adapter.Status}},
                       IPv4Connectivity,
                       NetworkCategory
}

#view the output in a nice interactive table
$results | Out-GridView
```

alternative output as a table:

```
$results | Format-Table
```

output:

```
Name  DeviceName                                     InterfaceDescription                Status IPv4Connectivity NetworkCategory
----  ----------                                     --------------------                ------ ---------------- ---------------
Wi-Fi \Device\{FC0C77D5-E521-46C9-A11D-A1E018ED8DEA} Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 Up             Internet         Private
```

Comment: Justin, fyi... I just ran your code, and it does not work. $results is never populated,

Comment: i just tested with a brand new powershell instance after copy/paste from this post and it works for me, i've included the output. I've also tested on both windows server 2012 + 2016 and it works on them as well.

Comment: this looks cool but again it doesnt return the "Connectivity" status as noted in my screenshot "Internet access" or "No internet access". IPv4Connectivity does not appear to be the same thing.

Comment: If connectivity is "internet" it means it has internet access, if it is "LocalNetwork" then it does not. I tested this by unplugging my modem (internet) but leaving router on (wifi/local network).

Comment: @user3436467 did this solve your problem? if so can you please mark the answer as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: For those to whom the code doesn't work replace `$Adapters = Get-NetAdapter -Physical` with `$Adapters = Get-NetAdapter` (for example if you use virtual switch)

Answer (score 2):

Use WMI to do this.

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | select netconnectionid, name, InterfaceIndex, netconnectionstatus
```

Look at netconnectionstatus. You will find a value there. That is the connectivity status.

0

Disconnected

1

Connecting

2

Connected

3

Disconnecting

4

Hardware not present

5

Hardware disabled

6

Hardware malfunction

7

Media disconnected

8

Authenticating

9

Authentication succeeded

10

Authentication failed

11

Invalid address

12

Credentials required

Comment: This does not accurately reflect my screenshot.

For example Ethernet 7 shows:
Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device #9   Connected

However, in my screenshot it shows "no network access", and this is the correct one because internet is down on that adapter